# Pybrain installed but runs only from terminal

Tags: python, pybrain

Here's the problem: after a lot of struggle I managed to instal pybrain, but it runs only from terminal when I use the command export 'PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:'. When I try to import modules and write in Python (through anaconda) I get this error 'no module named pybrain'. It's as if Anaconda couldn't see that pybrain is right there. Could it be a problem with the directory?
I don't understand what it means: 
"Change into the directory Pybrain directory after either checking out got or downloading and extracting the archive. There you run (possibly as a superuser on Unix systems):

$ python setup.py install"

which I found on 'http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/installation.html'

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to install it properly to Anaconda:

```
pip install -i https://pypi.binstar.org/pypi/simple pybrain
```

That should work. The process to find out why is lengthy, and I'll follow up soon.

**Proof:**

[image]

Comment: Yes, from the terminal. Just type it in. If it errors out, let me know. I'm writing up the steps that led to this so you can have a reference. Bear with me.

Comment: ok, i got this:    MacBook-Pro-di-macbookpro:~ macbookpro$ pip install -i https://pypi.binstar.org/pypi/simple pybrain
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pybrain in /anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py3.4.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy in /anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from pybrain)
Cleaning up...
MacBook-Pro-di-macbookpro:~ macbookpro$

Comment: Fair enough. When you type `python` in the terminal, do you see explicitly that the Python environment you're entering is the one from the Anaconda distribution? You can see this in the screenshot above: `Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics`.

Comment: not really the same but almost:    MacBook-Pro-di-macbookpro:~ macbookpro$ python
Python 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, Sep 10 2014, 17:24:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: I have this really bad feeling that you are having conflicted installs. Seems like Anaconda is the default Python but it's not searching the Anaconda directory for the modules. However, from the steps below, that shouldn't be the case once you've done the PYTHONPATH step. By any chance, besides the built-in Python in OSX, did you install other distributions or Python versions (ie. 2.7.8, 3.3.x, etc)?

Comment: yes, before I installed an older version of anaconda... and actually I substituted the standard pybrain folder with the 'master one' in order to get some modules fixed. Should I replace it with the older one?

Comment: At the risk of sounding harsh, err, I can't even begin to comprehend the logic of that. Okay, this is a bit of a radical move, but is a thermonuclear reset a valid option for you? The way I'll do this is to uninstall Anaconda completely. The above was just done right now, for the sake of testing if `pybrain` works, which it did, albeit on a Windows end. Gauge if this is a viable option for you. If you are, we'll move to chat and I'll guide you even if I don't have experience with OSX.

Comment: Oh, crap. You need 20 rep to chat. :/ Anyway, try reinstalling Anaconda for the meantime. Let's start from scratch.

Comment: I know it's something really unusual but would you chat on skype?

Comment: ok maybe I'm asking too much, sorry for that. In order to reinstall Anaconda should I uninstall it or just open the packages again?

Comment: is this ok for removing? rm -rf ~/anaconda

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. At work. ;) Uninstall it completely. Don't just delete the folder. Uninstalling would also reset the PYTHONPATH to its original setting (the default Python of OSX). Once you've uninstalled it, reinstall it again. Make sure you have the newest version for Python 3.x Anaconda. Then we'll go through the proper steps of installing `pybrain`.

Comment: hey nanashi thanks, I was just wandering about how to uninstall anaconda. On the site (http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html#linux-osx-uninstall) I read I should use the rm command, what do you think?

Comment: Follow the instructions on their site then. I don't have experience in OSX so I wouldn't know how to uninstall it. After that, try checking where you PYTHONPATH defaults to.

Comment: Nice, so it's pretty much clean. Three-way tag-team with @Will Campbell. Anyway, now that your PYTHONPATH is reset, make sure to install the latest Python 3.x Anaconda distro for OSX. Once it's installed, **DO NOTHING YET**. Print out your PYTHONPATH and post it back here.

Comment: Will told me to install the version 2.7 of python... but the last version of anaconda gets me python 3.4 right?

Comment: I don't think the library itself has examples. Better check the docs online: http://pybrain.org/docs/.

Comment: No problem. I just remember seeing you yesterday and I was aghast you still haven't resolved it. Remember, since you're using Anaconda, try `conda install <library>` before going for `pip` or anything else. If `conda` suggests you check `binstar`, do that as well. If nada, *then* use `pip`. Compiling or installing from source, even if others swear by it, is often beyond necessity.

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues could be that it's not permitting you to install this module.

Try this in your PyBrain directory:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

EDIT:

To navigate within terminal to the directory you use the `cd` - command. Let's say PyBrain is located in your desktop:

```
$ (this is where you'll be initially on your terminal)
```

EDIT 2:
To be in your root directory to be able to navigate to any file use the ../ command until you are there (it's appear as a house on your terminal window):

```
$ cd ../ 
$ cd ../
```

Then navigate to the directory:
    $ cd desktop/pyBrain

Or in your case:

```
$ cd anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pybrain-master
```

Further documentation about installation can be found here: https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/wiki/installation

EDIT 3:

Removing Anaconda:

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda
```

The rm command will remove the file, and the rf will force it to be deleted (otherwise it might not delete the directory).

Comment: the point is that maybe you know mac better... I'm trying to remove anaconda by sudo rm -rf but the terminal doesn't allow it... I can't type the password...

Comment: ok I managed to uninstall it... could you explain to me how to find the pythonpath?

Comment: great! do you think I should uninstall python too in order to get all cleaned and then reinstall everything?

Comment: No that's not necessary. I wouldn't recommend it either. It's all clean as of right now.

Comment: Use this link: http://repo.continuum.io/anaconda3/Anaconda3-2.1.0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg

Comment: Hey make sure you install the Python you have on your OS. That is, use Python 2.7 version of Anaconda. (just to be safe)

Comment: really? But with this version of anaconda python 3.4 gets installed right?

Comment: I mean, you used 3.4 the last time and that gave you errors. Just try 2.7 this time and if it works keep it. You can always upgrade later on.

Comment: @WillCampbell's logic is somewhat on the safe side, even though 3.4 shouldn't pose a massive issue, really. However, `pybrain` is largely lacking in updates, and it's obvious that some parts were written in the days of Python 2.7's prime. Use 2.7 for now. If it works, keep it, I say. I use 2.7 myself, due to sheer attachment by experience since hardly any library is lacking in compatibility with it.

Comment: Use this one then: http://09c8d0b2229f813c1b93-c95ac804525aac4b6dba79b00b39d1d3.r79.cf1.rackcdn.com/Anaconda-2.1.0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg

Comment: Use this one then: http://09c8d0b2229f813c1b93-c95ac804525aac4b6dba79b00b39d1d3.r79.cf1.rackcdn.com/Anaconda-2.1.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh

Comment: Install and print your PYTHONPATH. Post it here. Make sure to make it your default Python installation, if asked.

Comment: here it is:     //anaconda/bin/python

Comment: Ok, don't install anything else yet. Type `conda install pybrain`. If it installs, check if it imports. If not, post your error in your OP above.

Comment: Error: No packages found in current osx-64 channels matching: pybrain

You can search for this package on Binstar with

    binstar search -t conda pybrain

You may need to install the Binstar command line client with

    conda install binstar

Comment: That's alright. Now try my answer again: `pip install -i https://pypi.binstar.org/pypi/simple pybrain`. Check if it imports.

Comment: Installing collected packages: pybrain
  Running setup.py install for pybrain
    
Successfully installed pybrain
Cleaning up...

Comment: what do you mean with import?

Comment: Try importing `pybrain` now. If it doesn't error out, then the installation of `pybrain` is successful.

Comment: from the terminal or I can import it from anaconda?

Comment: Step-by-step: in the terminal, type `python`, press Return. Type `import pybrain`, press Return. If it errors out, then it wasn't installed properly. If it was, then you're all good.